# Is "looked at me funny" correct grammar?

Tags: expressions, verbs, idioms, flat-adverbs

The following phrases:

> Looked at me funny
>
> Looking at me funny

Don't sound grammatically correct, but I hear them as turns of phrase relatively frequently. It should be something like:

> Looked at me funnily
>
> Looking at me funnily

Right?

But then the original sentiment of the phrase seems lost, as it's so seldom used. Is it valid for the adjective "funny" to implicitly modify the noun "the look" that is being received, or is this just another case of standardised bad grammar?

Comment: Why do you think that adverbs need to end in *-ly*? [They don't,  you know.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flat-adverbs) It’s like how “We’ll be drilling faster, deeper, and better” uses three adverbs in the comparative degree, and no adjectives at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, though it is arguably restricted to informal speech and writing.

*Funny* is here an **adverb**, with the meaning 'in an odd or peculiar way'. This usage is recorded e.g. in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funny) dictionary (you'll need to scroll down to the meaning of the word as an adverb). It is also recorded in the OED, with the note *regional and colloq.*